# Update one table based on data from another table with different data types

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable, sql-update

for example, I got table `order` looks like

```
| orderId | type |
| --------|------|
| 1       |   pig|
| 2       |   cat|
| 3       |   cat|
```

and here I got a table `adopt`

```
|orderId|type|
| --- |---|
|1    |  1|
|2    |  2| 
|3    |  0|
```

I want to update the `type` value(int) of  table `adopt` depends on the `type` value(string) of table `order`, `pig` means 1 ,`cat` means 2, so the third row in table `adopt` should look like `(3,2)`, is there any sql can make this work, or I should
use programming language instead.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with an update using `JOIN` between the two tables, or by updating adopt based on a select query from order, whichever way makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update adopt a
join `order` o on o.orderId = a.orderId
set a.`type` = case when o.`type` = 'pig' then 1
                    when o.`type` = 'cat' then 2
                    else 0 
               end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, `case when`  statement is useful